# OnRowUpdating does not work even if i have a !postback in page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner and I am creating a crud webpage in asp.net and i can't get the update(save) button working. here is the snippet of my code:

Save and Cancel buttons in Main.aspx

```
<div  height: 334px;" class="gridview">
            <asp:GridView ID="RetailInfoGridView"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ShowFooter="true"
                DataKeyNames="StockKeepingID"
                runat="server"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                AlternatingRowStyle="alt"
                EmptyDataText="No Records Found"
                AllowSorting="True"
                OnRowCommand="RetailInfoGridView_RowCommand"
                OnDataBound="RetailInfoGridView_DataBound"
                OnRowDataBound="RetailInfoGridView_RowDataBound"
                OnRowEditing="RetailInfoGridView_RowEditing"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="RetailInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowUpdating="RetailInfoGridView_RowUpdating"
                onRowDeleting="RetailInfoGridView_RowDeleting"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="RetailInfoGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">

                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Edit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Save" CommandName="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Add" CommandName="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" ToolTip="Add" />
                        </FooterTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

<EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Save" CommandName="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" />
</EditItemTemplate>

...
```

Main.aspx.cs

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=102000-LSU-2216;Initial Catalog=loginDB;Integrated Security=True";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateGridView();
            }
        }

        protected void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* connect.Open();
             string query = "SELECT * FROM RetailInfo WHERE StockKeepingUnit LIKE '%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'";
             adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connect);
             table = new DataTable();
             adapter.Fill(table);
             RetailInfoGridView.DataSource = table; 
             RetailInfoGridView.DataBind();

             connect.Close();*/
        }

        protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connect.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RetailInfo WHERE StockKeepingUnit LIKE '%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'", connect);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);


                RetailInfoGridView.DataSource = table;
                RetailInfoGridView.DataBind();

            }

        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='aquamarine';";
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='white';";
                e.Row.ToolTip = "Click the link to view Description";

                //e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(RetailInfoGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            }
        }

        void PopulateGridView()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connect.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RetailInfo", connect);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);


                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    RetailInfoGridView.DataSource = table;
                    RetailInfoGridView.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
                    RetailInfoGridView.DataSource = table;
                    RetailInfoGridView.DataBind();
                    RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                    RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                    RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = table.Columns.Count;
                    RetailInfoGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No record Found";

                }
            }

        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (e.CommandName.Equals("Add"))
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connect.Open();
                        string query = "INSERT INTO RetailInfo(StockKeepingUnit,UniversalProductCode,VendorName,ProductName,ProductDesc,RetailPrice) VALUES (@StockKeepingUnit,@UniversalProductCode,@VendorName,@ProductName,@ProductDesc,@RetailPrice)";
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockKeepingUnit", (RetailInfoGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("skuTextBoxFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniversalProductCode", (RetailInfoGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("upcTextBoxFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorName", (RetailInfoGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("vnTextBoxFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", (RetailInfoGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("pnTextBoxFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDesc", (RetailInfoGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("pdTextBoxFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetailPrice", (RetailInfoGridView.FooterRow.FindControl("rpTextBoxFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        PopulateGridView();
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Alert", "alert('New Record Added');", true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }   

        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            RetailInfoGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            PopulateGridView();
        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            RetailInfoGridView.EditIndex = -1;
            PopulateGridView();
        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    string query = "UPDATE RetailInfo SET StockKeepingUnit=@StockKeepingUnit,UniversalProductCode=@UniversalProductCode,VendorName=@VendorName,ProductName=@ProductName,ProductDesc=@ProductDesc,RetailPrice=@RetailPrice WHERE StockKeepingID=@id";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockKeepingUnit", (RetailInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("skuTextBox") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniversalProductCode", (RetailInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("upcTextBox") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorName", (RetailInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("vnTextBox") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", (RetailInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("pnTextBox") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDesc", (RetailInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("pdTextBox") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetailPrice", (RetailInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("rpTextBox") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(RetailInfoGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    RetailInfoGridView.EditIndex = -1;
                    PopulateGridView();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Alert", "alert('Record Updated');", true);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void RetailInfoGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    string query = "DELETE FROM RetailInfo WHERE StockKeepingID = @id";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(RetailInfoGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    PopulateGridView();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Alert", "alert('Record Deleted');", true);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Whenever I run the program, I edit values to a specific row and then I click the save button, it does not do anything. I have read other answers that said to have a !postback and DataKeyNames in the code but I already have the postback in Main.aspx.cs and the DataKeyNames on Main.aspx. I don't know if the error comes on the .aspx or on the .aspx.cs. Have I done something wrong on the code? any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on the `RetailInfoGridView_RowUpdating` method and do an update in debug mode? Is the breakpoint hit? Do you get the values you expect? Do you end up in the `catch` block (you shouldn't just swallow exceptions like that)?

Comment: @JonP I tried setting breakpoints on `RetailInfoGridView_RowUpdating` and it still does not do anything. I also removed the exceptions because earlier, I thought it may help.

Comment: Does nothing... so does that including hitting the break point? Can you step into that function?

Comment: @JonP when I put breakpoints on the `RetailInfoGridView_RowUpdating` the hit count does not increment. I'm sorry I am just a beginner in visual studio

Comment: In that case you need to find some tutorials on setting and using break points to step into code using VisualStudio, it will become one of your most important debugging tools. I am not sure what you mean by incrementing the hit count, there is no mention of that in your code.

Comment: @JonP okay i will find some tutorials on breakpoints thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Here's some to get you going: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019 , https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/breakpoints/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I have solved the problem. instead of writing "save" variables:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Save" CommandName="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save" />
        <asp:Button ID="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I changed it to "update":

```
<EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="Update" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" ToolTip="Update" />
         <asp:Button ID="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Although I do not know why it worked, but it did the job!

If you know why "save" did not work and and "update" worked, I would really appreciate it if you tell me so i can be enlightened.

Thank you for all who helped.